# Tag Alias: naturalization -> citizenship

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Since naturalization is an act of obtaining a citizenship [naturalization](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naturalization) should be a synonym for [citizenship](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citizenship)